# JavaFX wait for user input

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am writing a board game where I need to check for enemies on the the player is moving and prompt to make an attack. However because of how the game is made the move method is called on the JavaFX application thread, I want to be able to prompt the user if they want to fight an enemy.

My dialogue box which works fine normal uses wait and notify which dont work on the main thread without crashing the program, does anyone know how to pause the execution of this thread until a user clicks one of the buttons.

I apologise for the description, its late.

**Method that checks for enemies**
This method checks for the enemies and returns the enemy if the user selected yes. It runs on the JavaFX Thread.

```
private Ship pathBattle(Vector gridPosition){
  //Check if there are ships on the path to the destination
  for(Button cell : activeButtons){
     //Check the button position is not that of the current button, dont go past the current button
     Vector pixPosition = new Vector(cell.getLayoutX(), cell.getLayoutY());
     //Convert to a grid referance
     Vector gridPos = Vector.pixToGrid(pixPosition);
     if(!gridPos.equals(gridPosition)){
        //This button is not the destination

        //Check for any ships on that cell
        Ship collided = Ship.isOccupiedButton(cell);//Returns the ship if there is one on the cell
        if(collided != null){
           //There is a ship, prompt to battle
           boolean battle = UtilPopups.showConfirmationDialog("Do you want to battle " + collided.getName(), "YAR!", "NAY!");

           Game.printError("Ship collision");

           if(battle){
              return collided; //Return the ship to battle
           }
        }
     }

     //On to the next button
  }

  return null;
}
```

**The code to display the Popup**
This does work in other areas of the porgram with no issue

```
public static boolean showConfirmationDialog(String lblPrompt, String btnYes, String btnNo){
  //Check if the confirmation controller is not null
  if(confirmationDialog != null){
     confirmationDialog.lbl_prompt.setText(lblPrompt);
     confirmationDialog.btn_no.setText(btnNo);
     confirmationDialog.btn_yes.setText(btnYes);

     //Show the base
     show(confirmationDialog.base_pane);

     //Pause this thread until user input is given from GUI thread
     synchronized (confirmationDialog) {
        try{
           confirmationDialog.wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     //Program resumed, user input given and stored in response
     if(confirmationDialog.response.equals("yes")){
        confirmationDialog.response = null; //Set back to null
        return true;
     } else {
        confirmationDialog.response = null; //Set back to null
        return false;
     }
  }

  //Class not initialized
  Game.printError("UtilPopups->showConfirmationDialog: Dialog NULL!");
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For blocking any caller thread during showing dialog, for example:

```
static private void showAndBlock(Dialog dialog) {
    if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
        dialog.showAndWait();
    } else {
        CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            dialog.showAndWait();
            lock.countDown();
        });
        try {
            lock.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Just in case you call yourTherad.interrupt(),
            // the thread will be joined forcibly through here.
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure whether or not it works in your threading design.

Answer (score 0):

The collided method literally doesnt nothing, it doesn't ask for a input so it can't work.

I think, sorry not good english

Comment: Its not a method, its a variable that has the value of a Ship(Enemy) or null if no Ship is present on that tile being tested.